# Disabling Auto Scroll UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to disable autoscroll to top. I tried both

```
    tableview.scrollsToTop=NO;
    [tableview setScrollsToTop:NO];
```

but that doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Are your sure your tableview property is valid when you set the property? Try adding a "- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView" delegate method and return NO.

Comment: So you know that tableView is set - you added a log message to print it out NSLog(@"%@", tableView)", you set the value, your tableview is setup to use your class as a delegate, and you have the delegate method that returns NO? Add a log to scrollViewShouldScrollToTop to see if it gets called. ScrollToTop is where you tap the Status Bar - this is the feature you want to disable, right?

Comment: No that is not I want. May be I am wrong about what I say. The problem is i have a table view with many rows.When cell is selected. it push some view controller. After, I press back button. It scrolls up(the selected row is at the top cell).So I don't want it to scroll itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The automatic scrolling code resides in tableViewController, so auto-scrolling can't be disabled. Instead of subclassing from UITableViewController you can subclass from UIViewController and use a tableView inside it.

If you are willing to use UITableViewController itself, you can override viewWillAppear and don't call [super viewWillAppear].